# Position tkinter simpledialog

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tried to position (by .geometry()) the following AskOkCancel dialog.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import textwrap
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog


class AskOkCancel(Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, message=None):
        self.message = message
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(parent, title)

    def _center(self, parent):
        """Center self over parent"""
        def _getxy(w):
            return w.winfo_rootx(), w.winfo_rooty()

        def _getwh(w):
            return w.winfo_width(), w.winfo_height()

        def _getreqwh(w):
            return w.winfo_reqwidth(), w.winfo_reqheight()

        self.update_idletasks()
        xo, yo = _getxy(parent)
        wo, ho = _getwh(parent)
        wi, hi = _getreqwh(self)
        # 'wxh±x±y'
        self.geometry('+{:d}+{:d}'.format(
            xo + (wo - wi) // 2, yo + (ho - hi) // 2))

    def body(self, box):
        self.lift(aboveThis=self.parent)
        tk.Label(box, text=textwrap.fill(self.message, width=40), height=3,
                 relief=tk.SUNKEN).grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0)
        self.chkvar = tk.IntVar()
        self.chk = tk.Checkbutton(box, variable=self.chkvar,
                                  text="Remember my answer")
        self.chk.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.result = False, None
        self._center(self.parent)
        return self.chk              # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        self.result = True, self.chkvar.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('800x800')
    d = AskOkCancel(parent=root, title='askokcancel',
                    message=('"./pypass.db" already has fyp.ebay.com, '
                             '"continue?"'))
    print(f'{d.result = }')
```

I experimented with the .geometry() call above. 'WxH' part of a geometry string works, '+X+Y' has no effect.

Is

```
self.lift(aboveThis=self.parent)
```

necessary? Without it the dialog window is covered by root (tk.Tk() ) window.

Using Python 3.9.2, Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the source code of `simpledialog`, you will find that `geometry()` is executed after executing `body()`, so it will override `_center()`.

Based on the source code of `simpledialog`, you can override `deiconify()` which is executed after the internal call of `geometry()`:

```py
class AskOkCancel(Dialog):
    ...
    def deiconify(self):
        self._center(self.parent) # center the window
        super().deiconify()  # call the original function
```

Note that you don't need to call `self._center()` inside `body()`.

Comment: That was the piece of missing documentation! After calling _center in deiconify() the .lift() call also became unnecessary.